# Why does it give me a 401 unauthorized error even though I allow everyone to access the route?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-security

In my Spring Security config, I make it clear that I want all clients to be able to access my `/user` route. As I describe below:

```java
package com.api.business_manager_api.Config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorizeConfig -> {
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers("/user").permitAll();
                            authorizeConfig.anyRequest().authenticated();
                        })
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

However, even so, I cannot make a Postman request on the route, as it returns a 401 unauthorized error. But if I am using `permitAll()`, why is it giving this error? How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a your authentication type as **Basic Authentication** but you did not provide any bean to manage the **user** and the **password**. You can resolve it by:

1. You don't have to define a type of authentication in your client
2. If you choose **Basic Authentication** in your client, you have to define a **user** and **password**.

A sample code (don't use this in production):

```
@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager getUser() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
            User.withUsername("user")
                    .password("{noop}password")
                    .authorities("read")
                    .build()
    );
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```